# Match statement with dynamic value (`self.n`) matching even when value matched on != n

Tags: rust, match

My very first rust question. Searched large and far but haven't found the answer yet.

```rust
pub fn open(&mut self, row: usize, col: usize) {
    let n = self.n; // first question, I had to use this, I couldn't just use self.n as matching expression...
                    // ... a bit more stuff here
    match row {
        1 => {
            do_up = false;
            self.union(self.cell(row, col), 0)
        }
        n => {
            println!("this");
            do_down = false;
            self.union(self.cell(row, col), self.n)
        }
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

In my app, `row` can have different values from 1 to `n`. The result I am getting is that all other rows than 1 enter the `n` option.

What I want is that the option 1 code only runs when row is indeed 1, and the `n` option only when it's indeed `n` (e.g. if `n` is 5, then only match `row == 5`), and all the other values for `row` just get skipped.

Also, bonus question, if I put `self.n` directly as an option, then `rustc` complains. I had to introduce  `let n = self.n` for it to compile. My intuition tells me that the actual reason why it's not working as intended is related to just that...

Comment: Can you narrow this to one _specific_ technical question, summarized in the title? Putting multiple questions in a single SO question makes it eligible as close as "too broad", and a title should help others with the same problem identify clearly whether a questions answers will help them; "don't get" can mean different things.

Comment: ...I've tried to edit the title to be more specific myself; feedback on whether that's an improvement would be welcome.

Comment: What’s the difference between match `n` and `_`?

Comment: Yes, I guess match guards is what I need. I wasn't really sure what I was looking for. I guess in that case the question can be closed.

Comment: Although it's still not working for me. I have `match row {... row if row == self.n => {}}` but this never matches at all!

Comment: @transient_loop Please open a new question with your new code. This isn't enough code to answer your second question, and it's an independent problem. Further, please provide a [MRE], with a `main`, `use` statements and no undefined variables/types.